# MYSQL does not equal to issue

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT product_id, value
FROM products_vals
HAVING value <> 'london' 
ORDER BY product_id
```

Below is the table products_vals

```
product_id   value
29778        London
29778        England
29778        Mayfair
29778        Earls Shop
29779        Birmingham
29779        England
29779        St Kings
29779        Johns Shop
```

But when I use my query it always returns this(below).

```
29778   England
29778   Mayfair
29778   Earls Shop
29779   Birmingham
29779   England
29779   St Kings
29779   Johns Shop
```

As you can see the only thing it removes is the London row, what I am trying to achieve is to remove all the product_id that the London row shares so my query would look like.

```
29779   Birmingham
29779   England
29779   St Kings
29779   Johns Shop
```

Thank you.

EDIT :: can someone suggest a way of doing it using having caluse with aggregate functions.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT product_id, value
FROM products_vals
where product_id not in (select product_id from products_vals where value='london')
ORDER BY product_id
```

EDIT:

Not exactly sure what you are looking for, but if you mean that you want to be able to eliminate more than one city and are doing this:

```
SELECT product_id, value
FROM products_vals
where product_id not in (select product_id from products_vals where value='london')
and  product_id not in (select product_id from products_vals where value='gloucester')
```

ORDER BY product_id

Then you could do this:

```
SELECT product_id, value
FROM products_vals
where product_id not in (select product_id from products_vals where value in ('london','gloucester'))
ORDER BY product_id
```

Comment: is there a way of doing it using having clause, maybe using aggregate functions?

Comment: Probably. Is there something wrong with the way I've done it?

Comment: no it works, but for every subquery i do it adds about 15 seconds. Which is far from pleasing. So i thought maybe if someone could provide me with some aggregate functions using the having clause maybe that could work

FYI I have a very large database so speed and efficiency is key!

Comment: What subqueries are you  adding?

Comment: @PedroBernardo how about that?